# Объясните пожалуйста, почему плохо вызывать синхронные методы в асинхронной обертке (C#)

Tags: c#, async-await

Часто всплывает тема "истинной" асинхронности. Также часто слышу, что заворачивать синхронный метод в асинхронную обертку - это плохо. Пусть у меня есть такой вот код:

```
class Program
{
    static string GetResult(int id)
    {
        // Очень долги, идущий в базу, синхронный, блокирующий метод
         ...
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       var res = await Task.Run(() => GetResult(123));
    }
}
```

Чем это плохо, я имею в виду, завернуть блокирующий метод в `await Task.Run(...)`?
Можете простыми словами расписать суть проблемы? Был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: Так а кто сказал, что это плохо?

Comment: @tym32167 я читал, что такого рода код будет блокировать поток из пула.

Comment: Прочитайте [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async), а конкретно ощутите разницу между CPU-bound операцией и I/O-bound. А плохо тем, что запуск лишнего потока, когда это можно не делать - это нецелесообразный расход ресурсов компьютера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При данном подходе будет простаивать один поток в ожидании ответа от базы данных. Не сказать что это решение ужасающе плохое, но есть ряд сценариев, когда желательно бы этот поток занять какой-то другой работой.

Например: высоконагруженный сервис плохо обслуживает клиентов из-за дефицита свободных потоков в пуле.

Более правильное решение это переписать GetResult таким образом, чтобы все операции с базой данных происходили через асинхронное API. В таком случае, поток просто отправляет запрос в базу данных, и освобождается. Ответ от БД будет обработан в любом свободном потоке.

UPD: Очень рекомендую почитать блоги этого парня: [Stephen Cleary - Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). Многие веши проясняют.
Конкретные ссылки по теме:

- [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)
- [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Even in the Complex Case, Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня есть уточняющий вопрос. А если у меня нет асинхронного апи для базы? Ну вот такой вот код достался, Там такой синхронный провайдер к базе. Получается, остается смириться с тем, что у меня все синхронное? Оборачивание в Task.Run даст лишь видимость, что работать можно асинхронно, но, на самом деле, эффект будет такой же, как будто, я просто работаю синхронно? Верно?

Comment: В большинестве случаев то что висит один поток в ожидании - это не страшно. Надо смотреть по ситуации.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak -  добавил в ответ пару ссыллок.

Comment: спасибо огромное! Я понимаю, что при маленькой нагрузке, не важно, что происходит блокировка) Суть уточняющего вопроса чуть-чуть в другом. Я хотел спросить то же самое ли, если я оборачиваю в Task.Run синхронный метод, что и просто обычный синхронный вызов?

Comment: то есть, по сути, все что я могу выиграть от обертки, это асинхронный интерфейс, как задел на будущее, когда, например, провайдер БД будет поменян на настоящий асинхронный? Так получается?

Comment: А, все, вижу, что по вашим ссылкам Стефан Клери все разъясняет прям четко и по полочкам.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak У него ещё и крутая книга есть по асинхронности, там очень удобно всё разложенно по юзкейсам.

Comment: @SmorcIRL да, я заметил. Но немного отпугнуло, что кукибук. Типа сборник рецептов. По асинхронности нашел "Concurrency in .NET Modern patterns of concurrent and parallel programming" Riccardo Terrell. Вроде классная, но пока только начал, думаю, по моим вопросам это понятно))